Пытаюсь вывести форму в шаблон, а он не выводится
forms.py
from django import forms

class MyForms(forms.Form):
    
    OPTION_ONE = 'Низкий'
    OPTION_TWO = 'Средний'
    OPTION_THREE = 'Высокий'
    
    OPTION =[
        (OPTION_ONE, 'Низкий'),
        (OPTION_TWO, 'Средний'),
        (OPTION_THREE, 'Высокий'),
    ]
    
    
    OPTION_ONE2 = 'Открытно',
    OPTION_TWO2 = 'Выполнено',
    OPTION_THREE2 = 'Отклонено',
    
    OPTION2 = [
        (OPTION_ONE2, 'Открыто'),
        (OPTION_TWO2, 'Выполнено'),
        (OPTION_THREE2, 'Отклонено'),
    ]
    
    MyBaseID = forms.IntegerField(widget = forms.HiddenInput(), required = True),
    
    Name = forms.CharField(initial='Назови задачу', 
                           max_length = 30,
                           error_messages =
                           {'max_length'  :  'Названия задачи не должно привышать 30 символов включая пробелы и табы'}),
    
    Description = forms.CharField(label='Описания',
                                  max_length = 300,
                                  error_messages =
                                  {'max_length' : 'Описания задачи не должно привышать 300 символов включая пробелы и табы'}),
    
    #  Так мы указаваем дату
    Due_date = forms.DateTimeField(label='Когда надо будет сделать',
                                   required = False,
                                   help_text = 'Видите дату в формате ГГГГ.ММ.ДД ЧЧ:ММ(Это поле необязательно для заполнения)',
                                   input_formats = '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M',
                                   error_messages = {
                                       'invalid' : 'Ввидете коретное значения даты и времени'
                                   }),
    
    # Эта штука даёт нам предоставить одно значения из нескольких
    Status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPTION2,
                               label = 'Выберите текущей статус', 
                               required = False,  # Показавает обязательно ли значения
                               initial = OPTION_ONE2,  # Показавает дефолтно аа чем оно будет
                               widget = forms.RadioSelect),
    
    Prior = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Укажите приоритет задачи',
                              choices = OPTION,
                              required = False,
                              initial = OPTION_TWO,
                              widget = forms.RadioSelect),
    
    
    
from django import forms

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from .models import Task
from .forms import MyForms

def list(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            MyBase = Task.objects.all()
    except Exception as e:
        raise Http404('Произошли технический траблы:', {e})
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'MyBase' : MyBase})

def number(request, id):
    IdBase = get_object_or_404(Task, id=id)
    form = MyForms(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            MyBaseID = form.cleaned_data["MyBaseID"]
            Name = form.cleaned_data["Name"]
            Description = form.cleaned_data["Description"]
            Due_date = form.cleaned_data["Due_date"]
            Status = form.cleaned_data["Status"]
            Prior = form.cleaned_data["Prior"]
            return render(request, 'id.html', {'IdBase' : IdBase, 'form' : form})
    else:
        form = MyForms()
        
    return render(request, 'id.html', {'IdBase' : IdBase, 'form' : form})

Шаблон
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'list/styles.css' %}">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

{{ form.as_p}}

</body>
</html>

Вот что выводит 
Пытаюсь развернуть то что я написал в формах(Пока только вывести без манипуляций) а формы в шаблонах не выводяться

Во-первых, покажите шаблон текстом вместо скриншота, а во-вторых, не забыли кэш в браузере почистить?

@andreymal шаблон скинул кэш чистил
